# Efficiently transforming data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What would be the best way to approach this problem using pandas and python?

I currently have a pandas data-frame in a relatively awkward format, for example:

```
        Country      Indicator  2000  2010
0   Afghanistan            foo     1   2.5
1   Afghanistan            bar     3   4.5
2   Afghanistan            zoo     5   6.5
3       Bolivia            foo     7   8.5
4       Bolivia            bar     9  10.5
5       Bolivia            zoo    11  12.5
6      Cameroon            foo     2   1.5
7      Cameroon            bar     4   3.5
8      Cameroon            zoo     6   5.5
9       Denmark            foo     8   7.5
10      Denmark            bar    10   9.5
11      Denmark            zoo    12  11.5
```

Say that I want to split this into two separate data-frames for each respective year.

For 2000:

```
   foo bar zoo
0   1   3   5
1   7   9   11
2   2   4   6
3   8   10  12
```

For 2010:

```
    foo  bar   zoo
0   2.5  4.5   6.5
1   8.5  10.5  12.5
2   1.5  3.5   5.5
3   7.5  9.5   11.5
```

What might be the most efficient way to carry this out in pandas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df1 = df['Indicator', '2000'].pivot(columns='Indicator', values='2000')`
`df2 = df['Indicator', '2010'].pivot(columns='Indicator', values='2010')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This transformation is called "pivoting", or sometimes "casting" or "unmelting". It's so common that [it's covered by specific functions in the api.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df_years = df.pivot(index='Country', columns='Indicator', values=['2000', '2010'])    

            2000             2010           
Indicator    bar  foo   zoo   bar  foo   zoo
Country                                     
Afghanistan  3.0  1.0   5.0   4.5  2.5   6.5
Bolivia      9.0  7.0  11.0  10.5  8.5  12.5
...
```

This results in [multi level columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex):

```
df_years['2000']                                                                                                                                                                                    

Indicator    bar  foo   zoo
Country                    
Afghanistan  3.0  1.0   5.0
Bolivia      9.0  7.0  11.0
...
```

```
df_years['2010']                                                                                                                                                                                   

Indicator     bar  foo   zoo
Country                     
Afghanistan   4.5  2.5   6.5
Bolivia      10.5  8.5  12.5
...
```

You should just work with these, but if you want flat dataframes, you can assign like this:

```
df_2000 = df_years['2000']

Indicator    bar  foo   zoo
Country                    
Afghanistan  3.0  1.0   5.0
Bolivia      9.0  7.0  11.0
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Good to know that "pivoting" is a common transformation and can be handled by .pivot()

Answer (score 0):

Using [pivot-table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) allows you to save a sequence of labels: foo, bar, zoo.
For 2000 year:

```py
df2000 = df.pivot_table(index='Country', columns='Indicator', sort=False)['2000']

print(df2000)

Indicator    foo  bar  zoo
Country                   
Afghanistan    1    3    5
Bolivia        7    9   11
Cameroon       2    4    6
Denmark        8   10   12
```